# How to have variable scoping inside Jest's it's?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I created this test for a `push` util (that creates a new array) I created:

```
export const push = (array, value) => [...array, value]

describe('push', () => {
  const a = ['1']

  it('creates copy', () => {
    const b = a
    b.push('2')
    expect(a).toBe(b)
  })

  it('creates clone', () => {
    const b = a
    console.log(a)
    push(b, '2')
    expect(a).not.toBe(b)
  })
})
```

I was surprised to find out that `console.log(a)` yielded: `[ '1', '2' ]`. I thought `b.push('2')` wouldn't leave its surrounding `it`.

How to make the code inside `it` only apply to the scope?

Comment: `const b = a.slice();`  - it will create new array object

Answer (score 1):

When `b` is referring to the `a` in `'creates copy'` and you push 2 to it, you're modifying `a`(because they both are referring to same place and const doesn't prevent mutating operations like push).

When the second case, ie, `'creates clone'` is run, it uses the same `a`, ie, the one you had modified and hence will log `[ '1', '2' ]`.